# Inner product between a table and a column in sas

Tags: sas, data-manipulation, inner-product

I would like to calculate an inner product between a table (matrix) and a column (vector). Below are the sample datasets.

```
DATA tempdf ;
    input v1 v2 v3 ;
    datalines ;
1  2   3
2  4   6
3  6   9
4  8  12
5 10  15
    ;
RUN ;

DATA testcoef ;
    length Variable $3. ;
    input Variable $ coef ;
    datalines ;
v1 0.1
v2 0.2
v3 0.3
    ;
RUN ;
```

I want to calculate it by `v1*0.1 + v2*0.2 + v3*0.3` by each row. And the final result will be look like :

```
1.4
2.8
4.2
5.6
7
```

as a column.

Which respectively calculated by

```
1*0.1 +  2*0.2 +  3*0.3 = 1.4
2*0.1 +  4*0.2 +  6*0.3 = 2.8
3*0.1 +  6*0.2 +  9*0.3 = 4.2
4*0.1 +  8*0.2 + 12*0.3 = 5.6
5*0.1 + 10*0.2 + 15*0.3 = 7
```

THANKS.

I have try to `proc transpose` the `tempdf` datasets and merge the `coef` columns in `testcoef` dataset then do array over all columns by multiplying with `coef` column, and eventually sum all the columns up.

But the process will be very slow if the dataset is large in rows, I wonder if there is any smarter or faster way to do it.

```
PROC TRANSPOSE data = tempdf out = temptrans name = Variable;
    var _all_ ;
RUN ;

PROC SQL ;
    create table trans_coef as
    select a.*, b.Coef
    from temptrans as a
    left join testcoef as b
        on a.Variable = b.Variable ;
QUIT ;

DATA out1 ;
    set trans_coef ;
    array colarr  COL: ;
    do over colarr ;
    colarr = colarr * coef ;
    end ;
RUN ;

PROC MEANS data = out1 sum;
    var col: ; 
    output out = out1_score(drop = _TYPE_ _FREQ_) sum = ;
RUN;

PROC TRANSPOSE data = out1_score out = final_out name = Cust;
    var COL: ;
RUN ;
```

`final_out` table will be like :

```
  | Cust |  COL1
-----------------
1 | COL1 |  1.4 
2 | COL2 |  2.8 
3 | COL3 |  4.2 
4 | COL4 |  5.6 
5 | COL5 |  7
```

Comment: Do you have SAS/IML?

Comment: @draycut Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROC SCORE.

```
DATA tempdf ;
    input v1 v2 v3 ;
    datalines ;
1  2   3
2  4   6
3  6   9
4  8  12
5 10  15
    ;
RUN ;

DATA testcoef ;
   retain _TYPE_ 'SCORE';
   length Variable $32;
   input Variable v1-v3;
   rename variable=_NAME_;
   datalines ;
New 0.1 0.2 0.3
;
RUN ;
proc print;
   run;
proc score data=tempdf score=testcoef out=t3;
   var V:;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow. `PROC SCORE` is also a good way to solve the question! I wonder if the procedure can automatically align the variables since the order of `testcoef` may be different to the column order of `tempdf`.

Comment: @DennyChen yes PROC SCORE is THE way.  Variable order is not an issue as the variables are matched on name.  You should read the documentation for PROC SCORE.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you

```
proc sql noprint;
   select count(*) into :d separated by ' '
   from testcoef;
quit;

data want(keep = value);

   if _N_ = 1 then do i = 1 by 1 until (z);
      set testcoef end = z;
      array c {&d.} _temporary_;
      c{i} = coef;
   end;
   
   set tempdf;
   array v v1 - v&d.;

   do over v;
      value = sum(value, v*c{_i_});
   end;

run;
```

Result:

```
value 
1.4 
2.8 
4.2 
5.6 
7.0
```

Comment: Is it possible to extend that solution to arbitrate "matrix/vector-dimensions"? I would have transposed the coefficients to one line beforehand so that you do not need to initialize the coefficients array with a fixed length.

Comment: Edited with a quickfix.

Comment: Great! It works! But could you please explain about the part :         
`array c {&d.} _temporary_;
c{i} = coef;` Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The Array c{&d.} creates a temporary array with &d. = 3 elements. The c{i} = coef fills up the array with values from the testcoef data set. Hope it makes sense :-)

Comment: @draycut `_temporary_` understood, thanks! But how come c{i} = coef can become c{1} = first value in coef and c{2} = second value ..., etc. I add `put c{i} = / ;` after `c{i} = coef` and it showed up with `c[1]=0.1`  `c[2]=0.2`  `c[3]=0.3 `. Does it mean that sas had created a temporary column call `c[1]` and assign the whole column with a single value that is 0.1 and same logic for the rest two columns?

Comment: The index values i come from the loop if _N_ = 1 then do i = 1 by 1 until (z); . Yes, that's a way to put it. A temporary array does not really create temporary columns, rather in-memory variables for us to use at later points .